# String or binary data would be truncated -- Heisenberg problem

Tags: sql-server-2005

When you get this error, the first thing you ask is, which column?  Unfortunately, SQL Server is *no help* here.  So you start doing trial and error.  Well, right now I have a statement like:

```
INSERT tbl (A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
SELECT A, B * 2, C, D, E, q.F, G
  FROM tbl
      ,othertable q
 WHERE etc etc
```

Note that

- Some values are modified or linked in from another table, but most values are coming *from* the original table, so they can't really cause truncation going back to the same field (that I know of).
- Eliminating fields one at a time eventually makes the error go away, if I do it cumulatively, *but* — and here's the kicker — **it doesn't matter which fields I eliminate**.  It's as if SQL Server is objecting to the total length of the row, which I doubt, since there are only about 40 fields in all, and nothing large.

Anyone ever seen this before?

Thanks.

**UPDATE:** I have also done "horizontal" testing, by filtering out the SELECT, with much the same result.  In other words, if I say

- WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 100: Error
- WHERE id BETWEEN 1 AND 50: No error
- WHERE id BETWEEN 50 AND 100: No error

I tried many combinations, and it cannot be limited to a single row.

Comment: As a debugging aide: You could try writing a cursor that goes over the source table and insert the rows one by one. Maybe the error lies in one of the rows?

Comment: What are the foriegn key constraints? Are there any?

Comment: @Vecdid - No, there are no constraints of any kind, not even a primary key.  It is just a throwaway copy of a remote table, used only during this routine, created by SELECT * INTO.

Comment: @harpo take a lok at this, check out this guys DataMgr component: http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/11/21/truncated

Comment: @harpo What exactly does B * 2 do? Never seen that before.

Comment: @Vecdid, B * 2 just indicates that some fields are manipulated in the query before being inserted into their original field.  This introduces the possibility of a numeric overflow, so it is relevant; however, as I indicated, I have checked all of the incoming values, and they are all well within range.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although the table had no keys, constraints, indexes, or triggers, it *did* have statistics, and therein lay the problem.  I killed all the table's stats using this script

http://sqlqueryarchive.blogspot.com/2007/04/drop-all-statistics-2005.html

And *voila*, the INSERT was back to running fine.  Why are the statistics causing this error?  I don't know, but that's another problem...

**UPDATE:** This error came back even with the stats deleted.  Because I was convinced that the message itself was inaccurate (there is no evidence of truncation), I went with [this solution](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/surpress-string-or-binary-data-would-be-) instead:

```
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF
INSERT ...
SET ANSI_WARNINGS ON
```

Okay, it's more of a hack than a solution, but it allows me — and hopefully someone else — to move on to other things.

Comment: Because the total stats attribute length was probably greater then [900 bytes][1]?
Not sure if this applies to statistics though and I'm not convinced.

Do you have a reference please because I'd like to know why stats would truncate when they are simply binary histograms (IIRC)

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you can't simply cast the fields as the structural equivalent of their destination column like so:

```
Select Cast(A as varchar(42))
, Cast(B * 2 as Decimal(18,4))
, Cast(C As varchar(10))
...
From Table
```

The downside to this approach is that it will truncate the text values at their character limit. However, if you are "sure" that this shouldn't happen, then no harm will come.

Comment: I have examined the data manually, and there is not a single value that should cause the error.  I checked the MAX(LEN()) of every varchar column against the size of the receiving field, as well as all numeric values.  Clearly something else is at work here, I just don't know what.

Comment: Then try casting all the columns to their destination table data type specs and see if the query will go through.

Comment: Or setting ANSI_WARNINGS OFF doing the INSERT and then comparing back against the original SELECT with the EXCEPT operator to see what didn't get inserted as expected.

Answer (score 1):

In some cases you can run into a problem if you have any other column with default values which might cause the problem.

Ex. you might have added a column to trace the user who created the row, like USER_ENTERED with default value of suser_sname() but the column length is less than the current username.

Answer (score 0):

If it looks like "total length" then do you have audit trigger concatenating the columns for logging?

Edit: after your update, I really would consider the fact you have a trigger causing this...

Edit 2, after seeing your statistics answer...

Because the total stats attribute length was probably greater then [900 bytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191241.aspx)?
Not sure if this applies to statistics though and I'm not convinced.

Do you have a reference please because I'd like to know why stats would truncate when they are simply binary histograms (IIRC)

Comment: I am checking wit the dba, but I don't believe so.  Would this mean that it's actually the *log* where the truncation warning originates?

Comment: log table, not transaction log. Eg "OrderHistory" matched to "Order" table

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when I ran into this, I had to create another table/tables which mimic the current structure. I then did not change the code, but changed my data type sizes to all nvarchar (MAX) for each field till it stopped, then eliminated them one by one. Yes long and dragged out but I had major issues trying anything else. Once I tried a bunch of stuff that was causing too much of a headache I just decided to take the "Cave Man" Approach as we laughed about it later.

Also I have seen a similar issue with FKs, where you must ask:

What are the foriegn key constraints? Are there any?

Since there are not any , try this guy's DataMgr component:

http://www.bryantwebconsulting.com/blog/index.cfm/2005/11/21/truncated

Also check this out:

http://forums.databasejournal.com/showthread.php?t=41969

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=138456

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=97349

You could also dump the table you are selecting from to a temp table and find out what line gives the error if it errors out to a temp table.

It should tell you the line in the error, if you put each column on another line, it should tell you exactly where it is bombing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a maximum row size limit in SQL Server 2005.  See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432%28SQL.90%29.aspx).

Most of the time you'll run into this w/lots of nvarchar columns.